# Why does `set` method defined on `Cell<T>` explicitly drops the old value? (Rust)

Tags: memory, rust, cell, borrow-checker, ownership

Interested why does `set` method defined on `Cell`, on the last line explicitly drops `old` value.
Shouldn't it be implicitly dropped (memory freed) anyways when the function returns?

```
use std::mem;
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;

pub struct Cell<T> {
    value: UnsafeCell<T>
}

impl<T> Cell<T> {
    pub fn set(&self, val: T) {
        let old = self.replace(val);
        drop(old); // Is this needed?
    } // old would drop here anyways?
    
    pub fn replace(&self, val: T) -> T {
        mem::replace(unsafe { &mut *self.value.get() }, val)
    }
}
```

So why not have set do this only:

```
pub fn set(&self, val: T) {
    self.replace(val);
}
```

or `std::ptr::read` does something I don't understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not needed, but calling `drop` explicitly can help make code easier to read *in some cases*. If we only wrote it as a call to `replace`, it would look like a wrapper function for `replace` and a reader might lose the context that it does an additional action on top of calling the `replace` method (dropping the previous value). At the end of the day though it is somewhat subjective on which version to use and it makes no functional difference.

That being said, the real reason is that it did not always drop the previous value when set. `Cell<T>` previously implemented `set` to overwrite the existing value via unsafe pointer operations. It was later modified in [rust-lang/rust#39264: Extend Cell to non-Copy types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39264) so that the previous value would always be dropped. The writer (wesleywiser) likely wanted to more explicitly show that the previous value was being dropped when a new value is written to the cell so the pull request would be easier to review.

Personally, I think this is a good usage of `drop` since it helps to convey what we intend to do with the result of the `replace` method.

Comment: Also, in debug builds, if something panics, having two different source line numbers may help pin-point the cause. Though I don't think `replace` can panic.